# How to get the keyboard locale of uitextfield

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a uitextfield object on the view controller. An user can input any text using any keyboard language.

The question is: How to get the language id of inputed text inside uitextfield by user selected keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Above iOS7.0

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
NSString *primaryLanguageId = textField.textInputMode.primaryLanguage;
}
```

iOS7.0 and below

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
NSString *primaryLanguageId = [UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to get string of launguage code using `[UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage` but  also you have to add observer because if keyboard launguage is chane then this observer notify the language is changed.

**Objective-C**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(changeInputMode:)
                                                 name:UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification object:nil];}
}

//This method prints the currently selected input language (like "en_US" or "de_DE"):

-(void)changeInputMode:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *inputMethod = [[UITextInputMode currentInputMode] primaryLanguage];
    NSLog(@"inputMethod=%@",inputMethod);
}
```

**Swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: "changeInputMode:",
                                                         name: UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func changeInputMode(notification : NSNotification)
    {
        let inputMethod = UITextInputMode.currentInputMode().primaryLanguage
        println("inputMethod: \(inputMethod)")
    }


}
```